# RJ45 Crimping - Do I have bad plugs?

Tags: networking, rj-45

I have a basic crimping tool that so far worked most of the times. I am a hobbyist when it comes to computers and networking.

Recently I bought a few new plugs and now crimping simply does not work. I do not hear a 'click' and after pressing it hard, eventually the plug remains in the tool and wires comes off if pulled.

I suspect the wires are not reaching the end of the plug where metallic contacts are present. The question is if wires do not extend full up to the end of the inside of the plug, will crimping happen or does it require presence of wires over the metallic contacts?

After failed crimping the plug looks the same just like rest of the other unused plugs.

Comment: *"I have to figure out if it's a plug or the tool"* -- You're ignoring other possibilities, i.e. the person who is not using the tool properly, and/or plugs that do not match the cable (wire gauge, and/or solid vs. stranded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must strip the outside shielding enough to fully insert the wires into the RJ-45 clip.  When you crimp the clip, you are actually pushing the wire tines into the cat-5/6 wires.  So, if they are not fully seated, they will not form an electrical connection and not function correctly.

Comment: Thanks. The question that I have is will I hear a click even if wires are not present? I suspect that the wires despite of having enough length are not getting fully inserted inside. I suspect they are a few mm short and from hereon I have to figure out if it's a plug or the tool. The tool was working fine up until a few days back. After I got new plugs the problem has started. I don't have old plugs to test it out. Now one option is to buy a new set of plugs from elsewhere.

Comment: You would only here the ratchet noise if nothing present . The "teeth" to set the wire to the connector are hardened metal. If not, they could fail.

Comment: I believe you would still hear the ratchet and click even with no wires inserted.  NOTE, there are two types of RJ-45 clips/jacks; one for stranded wire and one for solid core.  You may have purchased the wrong clips for the type of wire you are trying to crimp.

Answer (score 1):

I have a decent crimping tool - about $55 at the time I bought it. That said, it seems more like the crimper to me than bad plugs. You should hear a firm click when crimping. Decent RJ45 plugs are inexpensive and generally quality is uniform.

Even with good tools, I use pre-formed cables where I can